# Unable to run applications built in Xcode 5 in lower versions of xcode

Tags: xcode, macos

I have a Mac version 10.7.5 with Xcode 4.6.3 installed. I have an application built in Xcode 5 and this project doesn't open in my older Xcode installation. It shows me an error saying

> The document "Main.Storyboard" could not be opened.Could not read archive.Please use a newer version of Xcode. Consider changing the document's Development target to preserve compatibility.

Why am I not able to run this application using My Xcode.

Answer (score 5):

In Xcode 5, select the storyboard and in the `File Inspector`, make sure the following option is selected:

[image]

You should then be able to open it in Xcode 4.6.3.

Comment: A popup appears as specified in the question which doesn't allow you to edit the XIB, and when you respond to the pop up it de-selects the XIB. How would you resolve the same?

Comment: @thatzprem Open the XIB in Xcode 5 (as per my answer) and make the change in the File Inspector. Then close the XIB and open it in Xcode 4.6.x and you should be able to edit it.